# Can fire move ice in Sorry?

Tags: sorry

The [2013 version of *Sorry!*](https://www.hasbro.com/en-ca/product/_:590E1934-5056-9047-F59F-9F4E9B948900) adds fire and ice tokens. If my pawn with a fire token enters home can I move my other pawn that has the ice token?

The rules conflict. One one hand when the fire token pawn enters home it can move another pawn into home. On the other hand a pawn with the ice token may not be moved.

What is the correct ruling?

Comment: I haven't seen the game rules, but usually a "can't do something at all" overrides a "do something now" unless it says otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can not bring the pawn with the ice token to your home

As you say in your question, a pawn with a fire token **can** move a pawn into home. It states that it can do it and a pawn that cannot be moved, can therefore not be moved into home.